# Can't get ace editor with ASP.NET hot towel spa template to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ace-editor, hottowel

I'm new to web development, so please have mercy :)
I've created a new ASP.NET project with the hot towel template (http://nuget.org/packages/HotTowel/) and added

```
<script src="http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

to index.cshtml. Also, I modified home.html to look like this:

```
<section>
    <div id="editor">
        function foo(items) {
            var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
            return x;
        }
    </div>
</section>
```

At last, I changed home.js:

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Home View'
    };

    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log('Home View Activated', null, 'home', true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

When I run the application, Chrome tells me that ace.js has an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of null. Of course, the home screen won't show up. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like `var editor = ace.edit("editor");` line runs before `<div id="editor">` is created, make sure home.js script is included after `<div id="editor">` or is activated after document.onload event

Comment: Thank you, it works when I add an onClick event listener to the div and invoke the var editor = ... code therein. But this is suboptimal. What should be the way to invoke initialization code for a section in a hot towel web application?

Comment: i don't know any specifics about hot towel, but in a normal html page, i'd either move all scripts to the end of document, or add a check `if(!document.getElementById("editor"))document.addEventListener("load",initEditor,true)else initEditor()`

Answer (score 0):

@Papa Mufflon I’m not allowed to comment so I’ll put it as an answer.
HotTowel uses Durandal, which will call the `activate` function when the page becomes active (activate is exposed by the vm).

You can use activate as your 'on page load event'.
Just changing the `return true;` statement in the activate function to a `return yourDefinedStartupMethod();` should work. You may take a look at the `boot()` function usage in shell.js

There is a more detailed description of the behavior here http://oscarmeszar.com/hottowel-with-breeze-example/.